# How to use a script of a Docker container from CI pipeline

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

Newbie in Docker & Docker containers over here.

I'm trying to realize how can I run a script which is in the image from my bitbucket-pipeline process.

**Some context about where I am and some knowledge**

In a Bitbucket-Pipelines step you can add any image to run in that specific step. What I already tried and works without problem for example is get an image like `alpine:node` so I can run npm commands in my pipeline script:

```
definitions:
    steps:
        - step: &runNodeCommands
              image: alpine/node
              name: "Node commands"
              script:
                  - npm --version

pipelines:
    branches:
        master:
            - step: *runNodeCommands
```

This means that each push on master branch will run a build where using the `alpine/node` image we can run npm commands like `npm --version` and install packages.

**What I've done**

Now I'm working with a custom container where I'm installing a few node packages (like eslint) to run commands. I.E. `eslint file1.js file2.js`

Great!

**What I'm trying but don't know how to**

I've a local bash script `awesomeScript.sh` with some input params in my repository. So my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file looks like:

```
definitions:
    steps:
        - step: &runCommands
              image: my-user/my-container-with-eslint
              name: "Running awesome script"
              script:
                  - ./awesomeScript.sh -a $PARAM1 -e $PARAM2

pipelines:
    branches:
        master:
            - step: *runCommands
```

I'm using the same `awesomeScript.sh` in different repositories and I want to move that functionality inside my Docker container and get rid of that script in the repository

How can I build my Dockerfile to be able to run that script "anywhere" where I use the docker image?

PS:

I've been thinking in build a node_module, installing the module in the Docker Image like the eslint module... but I would like to know if this is possible

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you copy `awesomeScript.sh` to the `my-container-with-eslint` Docker image then you should be able to use it without needing the script in each repository.

Somewhere in the Dockerfile for `my-container-with-eslint` you can copy the script file into the image:

```
COPY awesomeScript.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

Then in Bitbucket-Pipelines:

```
definitions:
    steps:
        - step: &runCommands
              image: my-user/my-container-with-eslint
              name: "Running awesome script"
              script:
                  - awesomeScript -a $PARAM1 -e $PARAM2

pipelines:
    branches:
        master:
            - step: *runCommands
```

Answer (score 0):

As [peterevans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11934042/peterevans) said, If you copy the script to your docker image, then you should be able to use it without needing the script in each repository.

In your `Dockerfile` add the following line:

`COPY awesomeScript.sh /usr/local/bin/ # you may use ADD too`

In Bitbucket-Pipelines:

```
pipelines:
    branches:
        master:
            - step: 
                  image: <your user name>/<image name>
                  name: "Run script from the image"
                  script:
                      - awesomeScript -a $PARAM1 -e $PARAM2
```